# How can you implement an extension which connects to a service requiring MFA?

Tags: visual-studio-code, office365, vscode-extensions

How would you go about implementing an extension which connects to an external service(Office365) that has MFA required?

**Background**

I am currently using the extension SPGo(https://github.com/chrishasz/spgo) which allows users to interact with Microsoft SharePoint Online. My organization has recently required MFA and has disabled the ability to create an App Password as is described in this issue(https://github.com/chrishasz/spgo/issues/32#issuecomment-380171567).

I am trying to figure out if there is anything I could suggest to the implementer of this extension to make this work. If Visual Studio Code doesn't support any way to do this today, I would like to articulate a feature request to support this type of flow.

Answer (score 1):

MFA is the way to go indeed. It is easy for a browser application to authenticate use it, but desktop apps must do some extra work by directing the end user to the cloud authentication page using the `env.openExternal(uri)` API. The authentication service typically needs to be aware of your application and should know where to redirect the browser page upon successful MFA authentication. The redirect should go to some local `http://localhost:port/auth-callback`, which you must host temporarily from within your VS Code extension using `express`. Here is some pseudo code:

```js
import express = require('express');
import http = require('http');

import { env } from 'vscode';

function getLoginAndGetToken(onSuccess: (token: string, ...) => void, onError: (message: string) => void) {

    var server: http.Server = null;

    app.post('/auth-callback', function (req:any, res:any) {
        server.close();
        try {
            // todo: check nonce req.body

            // extract the tokens from `req.body`
            onSuccess(req.body.xyzToken, ...);
            // todo: put some confirmation in `res`
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } catch (err) {
            onError(err);
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
    });

    server = http.createServer(app);
    server.on('error', function (e) {
       onError(e.message);
    });
    server.listen(callbackPort);
    setTimeout( () => { server.close(); }, timeoutInMs );

    env.openExternal(cloudAuthUrl + nonce);
}
```

Then you use the token(s) in your communication with the cloud services.

Here is a tutorial for node.js web applications. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/node-tutorial It details the O365 OAuth2 specifics. You essentially need to refactor it into the pseudo-code above. Once you have it, please share.

Comment: I think I understand your pseudo code. It isn't clear to me how I might use the new env.asExternalUri to make this easier, but I think I will see if I can make it work with env.openExternal. Do you happen to know if anyone has actually done this with O365? It seems weird to me that I couldn't find any example VSCODE extensions that do something similar to use as an example.

Comment: Yes, the `vscode.env.asExternalUri` got clarified in the most recent VS Code release and no, it is not that relevant, so I removed that from the answer. I also added a link to a O365 OAuth2 tutorial for node.js, which has the details to put into the pseudo-code above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will take a look at the documentation and see if I can come up with the right way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

SPGo author here. I would really like to add support for Office 365 MFA in SPGo, but it is not currently possible until VSCode allows an extension author to open an external URI, and also access the HTTP Request/Response objects. This would require a functional combination of the [vscode.env.asExternalUri](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_39#_vscodeenvasexternaluri) and [vscode.env.openExternal](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#env) apis. The solution would work like this:

1. User configures SPGo to use MFA via the config wizard, or the *spgo.json* config file
2. SPGo would open a browser session, inside the extension context, pointing to the Office 365 MFA login screen.
3. upon successful login, SPGo would scrape the MFA token from the cookie collection on the session.
4. SPGo would then use that token for communication w/SharePoint Online until the cookie expires

My understanding of the solution that Jan mentions above is that it would work for an MFA Provider that supports API-based MFA, but Office 365 requires you to process the full MFA login via a single browser window. When I've experimented with this before, VSCode prevented me from opening browser sessions within the session. Maybe this has changed?

To answer your question specifically about how to help get this into SPGo - I would recommend the following:

1. Create an Issue on the Project GitHub. (One was recently created [here](https://github.com/chrishasz/spgo/issues/102))
2. Help author the solution by forking the repo, adding the functionality, and submitting a Pull request.

Thank you for using SPGo and I appreciate the feedback! Please help me track this issue via the link above.

Comment: I have seen the discussion on GitHub related to wanting MFA login, and I saw your similar response that vscode doesn't allow this. That is why I decided to open a question for vscode. Because it sounds like vscode needs to change in order to support this. My plan was to figure out if you could actually make MFA work and then see if I have the ability to help implement a solution. I hope that makes sense, I wasn't trying to go around the existing SPGo GitHub.

Comment: I do not thing anything is missing in VS Code. Node.js has all the pieces we need. We just need `vscode.env.openExternal`. Node.js helps you host an Express service to wait for the auth to be completed.